# Leer Archivo txt en java , con arrays

Tags: java

tengo que hacer que mi código corra el .txt, hacer el arreglo, guarde el numero de registros e imprima el arreglo, he estado intentando imprimir y creo que estoy bien hasta el guardado de archivo  pero no logro conseguir que haga lo que quiero. Este es el código que llevo, gracias:

```
    public void lee_archivo(){
    int numero_registro=0;  
        try {   

            FileReader fr= new  FileReader("C:\\Users\\KABEC160\\Desktop\\Escuela.txt");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 

            String Cadena;

            while ((Cadena=br.readLine()) !=null){

            numero_registro ++;

            }

            String [] lista_escolar = new String[numero_registro];

            numero_registro=0;

            while ((Cadena=br.readLine()) !=null){

                lista_escolar[numero_registro]=Cadena;

                numero_registro ++;

                }

            for (int x=0; x<Cadena.length();x++) {

                if (Cadena.charAt(x)==numero_registro) {    

                }
            }    

             System.out.println("Registro es: "+ lista_escolar[numero_registro]);   

    }
        catch(Exception ex){    
    }   
}

}
```

Comment: Hola, no logro entender lo que quieres y por ende tu problema.
Qué contiene el archivo "Escuela.txt"?
Cómo deberían formarse los arreglos?
Qué debería imprimir en consola?

Comment: Hola , siento no ser muy claro, el archivo TxT contiene una lista de 4 nombres, tengo que jalarlo de ahi para poder leerlo con un arreglo e imprimir en consola lo que el archivo contiene. espero poder haberme expresado mejor, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complementando lo dicho por **@Cadeq**
La verdad que no hace falta usar estrictamente un arreglo para hacer lo que buscas, usar arreglos complica las cosas porque es un tipo de dato estático, es decir, cada que vayas a agregar un nuevo elemento al arreglo y ya ha llegado al limite de su capacidad tienes que copiar todo el contenido en un nuevo arreglo + 1 espacio. Para atender este problema usamos otro tipo de dato más flexible llamado Listas (Hay más, por cierto).

En cuanto a la ruta del archivo, puedes simplemente crearlo dentro del proyecto Java que tienes creado, el IDE que usas tomará como referencia toda la ruta de tu proyecto Java y entenderá que el archivo está colocado en el mismo directorio.

[image: Archivo_dentro_proyecto_java]

El método quedaría asi:

```
public void leerArchivo()
{
    List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();

    try(FileReader fr = new FileReader("archivo.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr))
    {
        String linea;

        while((linea = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            lista.add(linea);
        }

        System.out.println("Cantidad de registros: " + lista.size());

        String [] arreglo = new String[lista.size()]; // Copiar el contenido de la lista a un arreglo de Strings, esto es opcional pero seguramente es una tarea escolar
        for(int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++)
        {
            arreglo[i] = lista.get(i);
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arreglo));
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

El archivo txt así (llamado archivo.txt)

```
Reynaldo
Bernard
De Dios
De La Cruz
```

Ejecutando el método, la salida en consola es:

```
Cantidad de registros: 4
[Reynaldo, Bernard, De Dios, De La Cruz]
```

Aqui tienes toda la clase completa por si tienes problemas: https://pastebin.com/raw/epWuAVaU

Answer (score 1):

El problema que estoy viendo con tu codigo es que quieres recorrer dos veces el fichero. Cuando terminas de recorrerlo por primera vez en `while ((Cadena=br.readLine()) !=null){`, la siguiente vez que intentes recorrerlo, no entrara en el while por que el buffer estará vació.

Te recomiendo que uses listas dinámicas como el arrayList en vez de una estática cuando no sabes cuantos registros tendrá el fichero.

Ademas veo que después de pasar por los dos while, tu `numero_registro` va a ser el doble de registros que tiene el fichero. O este codigo hace algo mas que has ocultado, o esta mal. Y por ultimo, la ultima parte del código es un sin sentido; para que un for con un if dentro si no se hace nada.

```
public void lee_archivo(){
    try {   

        FileReader fr= new  FileReader("C:\\Users\\KABEC160\\Desktop\\Escuela.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr); 
        String Cadena;

        //susituimos el array por un arraylist
        ArrayList<String>lista_escolar = new ArrayList<>();

        numero_registro=0;

        while ((Cadena=br.readLine()) !=null){
            lista_escolar.add(Cadena);
            }

        //A partir de aquí, tu código no tiene ningún sentido. No se sabe que quieres hacer ni por que haces un for y un if que no hacen nada.

        for (int x=0; x<Cadena.length();x++) {

            if (Cadena.charAt(x)==numero_registro) {    

            }
        }    

         System.out.println("Registro es: "+ lista_escolar.get(numero_registro));   

   }
    catch(Exception ex){    
   }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Después de leer el archivo para contar el número de registros / líneas del mismo, llegaste al final del mismo.

El siguiente intento de leer otra línea, ya no va a encontrar datos (digamos que estás en el fin de archivo).

Puedes utilizar el método mark() para indicar el inicio del archivo y después de terminar la lectura para conteo de líneas, regresar al inicio con el método reset().

Aunque en lugar de utilizar lectura secuancial, tal vez te convenga dar un vistazo a la lectura random.